# Remove extra space to the right in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I have extra white space to the right on Gmail when I use the vertical split. It's where the "people" widget used to be, but I don't want the widget nor the space. I just want the email to use up all the space.

[image: You'll see the space to the right, but still under the grey line.]

How can I remove this?

Comment: The Gmail interface has been changed a couple of times since this was posted. Is this still an issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I shrink the space on the right of the Gmail window after turning off "Chat"?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87193/how-do-i-shrink-the-space-on-the-right-of-the-gmail-window-after-turning-off-ch)

Answer (score 11):

If you're using Chrome, the wasted empty space can be removed by install the Chrome extension [Webmail Ad Blocker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webmail-ad-blocker/cbhfdchmklhpcngcgjmpdbjakdggkkjp).

Once installed, go to the Manage Extensions page in Chrome and choose Options for this extension. Then under the Gmail tab, on the right, turn off the tick labelled "People Widget". Note: this is better than turning it off in Gmail settings because the wasted space is also removed.

While I also have AdBlock Plus installed, I have found adding this extension along side it to be a better solution than adding a `mail.google.com##TD.Bu:last-child` filter to AdBlock Plus because that filter also causes emails to be completely blanked out when the email page is displayed by clicking a desktop notification for a new email received.

Answer (score 5):

From Rubén...:
"The default location of the chat widget is at the left. In order to show it in the right, the user should enabled the lab "Chat on the right".

In order to get rid of the widgets right panel go to https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/labs and disable the "Chat to the right" lab. Don't forget to click on the save button before leaving the labs settings page."

Comment: This is the correct answer. Other suggestions work but are 'hacks'. This 'labs' setting is the actual source of the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but as this came up first when googling this issue with no other solution in sight, I figured it was ok to add to the discussion.

Using the StyleBox extension in Google Chrome, one could add this css to the page (after disabling the people pane in the gmail settings) and reclaim the space:

```
td.Bu div.nH.adC {
    width: 0;
}
```

Comment: I have to create a css containing this and put it on a webserver? Or is there another way? This answer could be more complete containing the information how to configure this in StyleBox

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

1. Install AdBlock Plus if you haven’t done so yet.
2. Open the AdBlock Plus options and add the following filter:
       `mail.google.com##TD.Bu.y3:last-child`

source: http://www.arnebrachhold.de/2011/08/08/hiding-the-ad-columns-in-gmails-new-split-pane-mode-firefox/

Comment: Use the filter 
"mail.google.com##TD.Bu.y3:last-child" 
to avoid a blank window when popping out the mail to new window

Answer (score 2):

It's because a `div` inside that `td` (`<td class="Bu">`) has a fixed width of `202px`, so probably the best solution would be some script that sets the element's width to 0 or `display: none`.

[image]

Also note that the respective space is the default ads space, so I doubt you will be able to remove it with standard settings. It is present whether you enable or disable the *People Widget*.

Answer (score 2):

This tampermonkey script worked for me:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Fix gmail splitview
// @namespace    http://your.homepage/
// @version      0.1
// @description  enter something useful
// @author       You
// @match        https://mail.google.com/mail/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

function addGlobalStyle(css) {
    var head, style;
    head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    if (!head) { return; }
    style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.innerHTML = css;
    head.appendChild(style);
}

addGlobalStyle('td.Bu.y3 {display: none;}');
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use uBlock Origin.
Add this filter

```
mail.google.com##.y3.Bu
```